# Jodatime malformation even if it looks correct

Tags: java, jodatime

I have this piece of code

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z");
DateTime dateNow = dtf.parseDateTime(new DateTime().toString());
String registerDateStr = dateNow.toString();
```

But when I run it, it says malformed date:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-06-13T17:57:47.420+08:00" is malformed at ".420+08:00"

The date formed seems correct to me? Did I do something wrong with the format?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re working too hard. You don’t need any explicit formatter at all.

```
    DateTime dateNow = new DateTime();
    String registerDateStr = dateNow.toString();

    System.out.println(registerDateStr);
```

Output when I ran just now:

> 2019-06-13T13:04:48.301+02:00

If you want, you can also parse the string back without a formatter, but I see no reason why you should since you will just get a `DateTime` object equal to the one you started out from:

```
    DateTime parsedBack = DateTime.parse(registerDateStr);
    System.out.println(parsedBack);
```

> 2019-06-13T13:04:48.301+02:00

Were you aware?

> Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project.
>   No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate
>   to `java.time` (JSR-310).

Quoted from [the Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Answer (score 1):

Your format doesn't specify the milliseconds and there's an unneeded space before the timezone information.

This format will work:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Comment: oh yeah, Didn't see it correctly in the documentation. I thought it was a small 's'. This fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the result be

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

From the javadoc,

```
Symbol         Meaning                     Presentation      Examples  
------      -------                     ------------      -------

   H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
   m       minute-of-hour              number            30
   s       second-of-minute            number            55
   S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
```

Your format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z didn't work because, you left out `S` (fraction of second, which is present in your string as .420)